# Why do they call it jacking off?

Tags: history

Where did it come from?  What is the history of the idiom? I read it could from several different places but none of them seem like the right answer. Anyone got a good guess?

Comment: Jack off (v.) *"to masturbate" is attested from 1916, probably from jack (n.) in the sense of "penis*. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/jack--off -  *or from the verb jack in the sense of raising/hoisting.* - https://neologisms.rice.edu/index.php?a=term&d=1&t=15208

Comment: See also [jerk off](https://www.etymonline.com/word/jerk%20off#etymonline_v_35215).